# Exception while parsing xml in android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I try to parse xml from [this](http://deals.ebay.com/feeds/xml) source

Following is my parsing code:

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (parser.getName().equals("Title")) {
                        current_tag = tag_title;
                        deal = new Deals();
                    }
                    if (parser.getName().equals("MSRP")) {
                        current_tag = tag_msrp;
                    }
                    if (parser.getName().equals("ConvertedCurrentPrice")) {
                        current_tag = tag_convertedprice;
                    }
                    if (parser.getName().equals("SavingsRate")) {
                        current_tag = tag_savings;
                    }
                    if (parser.getName().equals("SmallPictureURL")) {
                        current_tag = tag_icon;
                    }

                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (parser.getName().equals("Item")) {
                        current_tag = -1;
                        deals.add(deal);
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    String value = parser.getText();
                    switch (current_tag) {
                        case tag_title:
                            deal.setTitle(value);
                            break;
                        case tag_msrp:
                            deal.setMSRP(value);
                            break;
                        case tag_convertedprice:
                            deal.setconvertedPrice(value);
                            break;
                        case tag_savings:
                            deal.setSavings(value);
                            break;
                        case tag_icon:
                            System.out.println("Icon for the current deal is: "+value);
                            deal.setIcon(value);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    current_tag = -1;
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

At the line `eventType = parser.next()` I get the following exception:

```
07-19 10:43:23.262: W/System.err(922): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: /link read: head (position:END_TAG </head>@1:427 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40dee498) 
07-19 10:43:23.272: W/Trace(922): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-19 10:43:23.272: W/Trace(922): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-19 10:43:23.282: W/System.err(922):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readEndTag(KXmlParser.java:970)
07-19 10:43:23.282: W/System.err(922):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:372)
07-19 10:43:23.282: W/System.err(922):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
07-19 10:43:23.282: W/System.err(922):  at com.nykkos.dailydeals.Parsers.parseDeals(Parsers.java:91)
07-19 10:43:23.282: W/System.err(922):  at com.nykkos.dailydeals.WebServices.downloadDeals(WebServices.java:37)
07-19 10:43:23.282: W/System.err(922):  at com.nykkos.dailydeals.DealsActivity.run(DealsActivity.java:59)
```

I do not find any obvious reasons as to why this happens.

Any help in resolving this is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you made sure that you really parse the link that you posted? Because from what I can see in the trace, it seems as if you are parsing a HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that you don't try to parse the XML that you think. Instead you seem to parse a HTML document, which is not well formed. This happens because some of the HTML tags don't require closing tags and you actually run into one of them like in the following example:

```
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

So please make sure that you really try to parse the XML that you intend to. Either check the URL that you try to get the XML from. The link that you provided should actually work but maybe you have a typo in your code.

Additionally debug your code and check what's inside your InputStream. I guess inside there's something very different from what you expect.

Comment: the issue was I was using by mistake `http://www.deals.ebay.com//feeds/xml` instead of `http://www.deals.ebay.com/feeds/xml`

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out :) Good luck!