# Parsing Xml (Android) ( iso- 8859- 1 ) with XmlPullParser

Tags: android, iso-8859-1

This is my error:

> --> E/XML error(989): Error: expected: /link read: head
>   (position:END_TAG @49:8 in java.io.InputStreamReader@537f609c)

I am reading a xml - file with ISO 8859-1 encoding.

But it's impossible. In other encodings if that is posible, for example UTF -8 , ISO- 8859-15, but not with ISO 8859-1.

```
URL url = new URL(MYLINK)

InputStream mi;
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
    .openConnection();
    connection.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
int response = connection.getResponseCode();
Log.d("debug", "The response is: " + response);
mi = connection.getInputStream();
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(mi, "ISO-8859-1");
```

....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception while parsing xml in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744826/exception-while-parsing-xml-in-android)

Comment: bishan my XML file is correct. Is a rss font from a web page very important.